# Where clause not working when trying to compare data passed into a function with the data in the database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to compare two values; one in the database and the other is passed to the method , which has the query in it, in the database class. When I try to run, the app crashes.

Code which sends the data:

```
projectdatabase db = new projectdatabase(this); 
    String gotid = db.getProjectName(id);
```

Code of the method in the database class which executed the query:

```
public String getProjectName(String id) {                   

    String[] columns = new String[] {PROJECT_NAME,KEY_ROWID};
    Cursor c = projectDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iID = c.getColumnIndex(PROJECT_ID);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(iID);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Is there something with my where clause?

EDIT:

Code implemented after Arash's answer:

```
public String getProjectName(String id) {                   

    String[] columns = new String[] {PROJECT_NAME,KEY_ROWID};
    Cursor c = projectDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
       int iName = c.getColumnIndex(PROJECT_NAME);

       for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(iName);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Log Cat:

```
12-31 15:25:15.193: W/dalvikvm(2134): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught   
exception (group=0x409c01f8)
12-31 15:25:15.257: I/dalvikvm(2134): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    
activity ComponentInfo{com.kk.project/com.kk.project.ViewProjectDetails}:  
java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at   
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at  
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at  
com.kk.project.projectdatabase.getProjectName(projectdatabase.java:123)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at   
com.kk.project.ViewProjectDetails.onCreate(ViewProjectDetails.java:19)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at   
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at   
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

12-31 15:25:15.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2134):     ... 11 more

Comment: Check My Edited Answer again,and plz always provide stack trace to your questions and tell which line cause NPE

Answer (score 0):

before using a cursor columns to avoid NPE , always check that your cursor have rows in it:

instead of :

```
int iID = c.getColumnIndex(PROJECT_ID);
```

use :

```
if(c.MoveToFirst())
{
   int iID = c.getColumnIndex(PROJECT_ID);
}
```

Edit : You don't have "PROJECT_ID" Column in your Cursor Selection Column

Second Edit :

Use Like This to get content of a Cursor :

```
String T = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Your_STRING));
Int I = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Your_INTEGER))
```

and you've assigned Project_Name to an Integer value!

Comment: you've used a column Index that doesn't exist in your Selection

Comment: I have updated my question description by adding your suggestions. It still gives a NPE. 
PROJECT_ID was not needed. It was supposed to be PROJECT_NAME.

Comment: Regarding your second edit, I don't think that is relevant because my approach too finally uses `getString()` plus I have used the same approach many times and it works. It is only this time, when I have used the where clause, my app is crashing. Anyway, I implemented your way too and the problem persists. I'll just put up the LogCat.

Also, thank you for the time and help!

Comment: I found the mistake. Probably the dumbest thing ever but I was not opening my database before calling `getProjectName();` 
Thank you for your help, though.

Comment: :)) good to hear that your problem solved but in later coding always check your Cursor first.Good Luck